# Android: Bitmap compression is causing out of memory problems

Tags: android, jpeg, android-bitmap, image-compression

I am trying to compress a bitmap that is picked from gallery or captured by camera before sending to server. Now I do it following these steps:

1) get the path of the image.

2) get bitmap from this path.

3) check initial width and height of bitmap, and compare them to the max width and height and then use a ratio factor to adjust width and height.

4) check and rotate bitmap correctly using exif.

5) finaly lower the quality to get a final compressed bitmap.

The code:

```
    private static final float max_width = 1280.0f;
    private static final float max_height = 1280.0f;
    private static final float max_ratio = max_width/max_height; 

    private void CompressImage(String path , Bitmap bitmap_original){



     //get width and height of original bitmap

     int original_width = bitmap_original.getWidth();
     int original_height = bitmap_origianl.getHeight();

     float original_ratio = (float)width/(float)height;

     if(original_height > max_height || original_width > max_width){
      //adjust bitmap dimensions

       int width = 0;
       int height = 0;

       if(original_ratio<max_ratio){
       width= (int)((max_height/original_height)*original_width);
       height=(int) max_height;  

       }else if(original_ratio>max_ratio){
        height= (int)((max_width/original_width)*original_height);
        width= (int)max_width;
       }else{
         height = max_height; 
         width = max_width;  
       }

       //adjust the bitmap 
        Bitmap adjusted_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap_original,width,height,false);


       //check rotation
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();  
       try{
       ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
       int original_orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION , ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);

         if(original_orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90){

          matrix.setRotate(90);

         }else if(original_orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_180){

          matrix.setRotate(180);

         }else if(original_orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_270){

          matrix.setRotate(270);
         }

         Bitmap rotated_adjusted_bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(adjusted_bitmap , 0 , 0 , adjusted_bitmap.getWidth(), adjusted_bitmap.getHeight(),matrix,true);


         //lower the quality

          ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          adjusted_rotated_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);
          Bitmap adjusted_rotated_lowquality_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));  

       }catch(IOException e){


        }


      }else{
      //keep bitmap as is
      Bitmap adjusted_bitmap = bitmap_original;
      }



     }
```

**The problem**

Everything above works fine, but the problem is that in some cases the app will crash with an Out Of Memory exception.

Is there something wrong with my code?

I don't know a lot concerning bitmaps and compression.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Is it crashes while displaying the image? Or you sending the image to server without displaying?

Comment: @MdSufiKhan just the compressing part is sometimes blocking UI with out of memory error.

Comment: @MdSufiKhan the displaying is handled by glide, but I dont know why the compressing is sometimes failing... maybe its because the bitmap is high res.

Comment: That's for sure the bitmap is in high res. Did you try to compress in separate Thread?

Comment: @MdSufiKhan  yes it is handled on background thread (async) task....but I just want to ask you is there something wrong with the above code. How to make sure I dont get out of memory for any kind of image?

Comment: You load the bitmap before compressing. I think this is the root cause of Out of memory error. You can have a look into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/31612736/2728085

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170396/discussion-between-md-sufi-khan-and-database).

Comment: @MdSufiKhan what do you mean to load bitmap before compressing? Otherwise what is the correct way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmap usually takes time and sometimes blocking I/O. So it's not good practice to call imageWithText on the UI thread.

> Glide is designed to be flexible and this problem demonstrates that
>   trait extremely well.

"Glide way" below, which I highly recommend.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
yourBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream); 
Glide.with(this).load(stream.toByteArray())
     .asBitmap() .error(R.drawable.ic_thumb_placeholder) 
     .transform(new CircleTransform(this)).into(imageview);
```

For further details check the link below

[Is there a way to load image as bitmap to Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42278134/is-there-a-way-to-load-image-as-bitmap-to-glide/42278907%2342278907&ved=2ahUKEwjCzOL74-zaAhUHWBQKHdyJDJcQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw3uqHON5bd_co2oyBgd8ynX)

Comment: how is that supposed to compress bitmap before sending to server?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the image uri when you select image from gallery as:

> Uri myUri = data.getData();

Before sending the image to server you need to convert that uri to byteArray[]

as below:

```
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),myUri);

   ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

   bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,0,baos);
                        byteArray[] bArray = baos.toByteArray();
    If you want you can get the name of image as:
     try (Cursor returnCursor = getContentResolver().query(myUri, null, null, null, null)) {
                        int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
                        int sizeIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE);
                        returnCursor.moveToFirst();
                           String FileName = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);}
```